# Trying to make a function that returns a tuple of the number of odds and evens in a list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I tried to do `value1 if expression1 else value2 for loop`

```
odds_evens(lista) = [odd,even odd+=1 if lista[i]%2==0 else even+=1 for i in range[0,len(lista)]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

I expect `odds_evens([1,2,3])` to give the answer `(2,1)`

Comment: I've got a lot of questions. First of all, what is `even odd`? Also, try expanding this into a regular for loop and if statement.

Comment: You haven't defined a function. You can't do `+=` , an assignment, in [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

Comment: So heres what I think is going on, he wants to print a tuple (num_odds, num_evens) and he is using a comprehension to count and add the totals to the tuple.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask], [mcve], and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution without for-loops:

```
def odds_evens(lista): 
    return (sum(num%2 == 1 for num in lista), sum(num%2 == 0 for num in lista))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(odds_evens([1,2,3]))
```

If you really needed to use a for loop, here's a way to do it:

```
def odds_evens(lista):
    odd = 0, even = 0 # Variable Initialization
    for i in range(0, len(lista)): # You did range[]. range is a method - range()
        if lista[i]%2==0:
            even+=1
        else:
            odd+=1
    return (odd, even) # Returns a tuple

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(odds_evens([1,2,3]))
```

Comment: Show your second solution first. Can entirely avoid for-loops.

Comment: @smci I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Before you jump into the comprehension, its easier to construct the code more in the more expanded version

```
lista = [1, 2, 3]
odds = 0 
evens = 0 

for i in range(len(lista)):
    if lista[i]%2 == 0:
        evens += 1
    else:
        odds += 1

odds_evens = (odds, evens)
print(f"odds_evens = {odds_evens}")
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/AtBS$ python3.7 pattern.py 
> odds_evens = (2, 1)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension and exploit the neat function `list.count(value)`. No need for for-loops:

```
def odds_evens(lista):
    remainder = [x % 2 for x in lista]
    return (remainder.count(0), remainder.count(1))

>>> lista = [1,2,3,5,7,8,9,10,12,13,17]
>>> odds_evens(lista)
(4, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the even (or odd) numbers need to be counted.

```
def odds_evens(lista):
    even = 0
    for i in lista:
        if i%2==0:
            even += 1
    return (even, len(lista) - even)
```